# Are there any values for gravatar_id in GitHub GET users/username responses?

Tags: javascript, json, github

Browsing through api.github, every user I look at, the gravatar_id value is empty.

The response data:

URL
https://api.github.com/users/angular

RES

```
{
"login": "angular",
"id": 139426,
"avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/139426?v=3",
"gravatar_id": "",
"url": "https://api.github.com/users/angular",
"html_url": "https://github.com/angular",
"followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/angular/followers",
"following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/angular/following{/other_user}",
"gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/angular/gists{/gist_id}",
"starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/angular/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
"subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/angular/subscriptions",
"organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/angular/orgs",
"repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/angular/repos",
"events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/angular/events{/privacy}",
"received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/angular/received_events",
"type": "Organization",
"site_admin": false,
"name": "Angular",
"company": null,
"blog": "angularjs.org",
"location": "",
"email": null,
"hireable": null,
"bio": null,
"public_repos": 95,
"public_gists": 0,
"followers": 0,
"following": 0,
"created_at": "2009-10-13T22:16:19Z",
"updated_at": "2015-04-12T01:40:18Z"
}
```

The value is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This field was [removed last year](https://developer.github.com/changes/2014-09-05-removing-gravatar-id/).  Most likely, Github chose to keep the key value in the response to prevent existing code from breaking